# How to test output of command pipeline

Tags: bash, shell

These two lines

```
 function some {
         ## myFunc(true) is just a pattern
         local isEnabled="grep myFunc(true) $indexFile | grep true"
         if [ -z $($isEnabled) ]; then ... fi
     }
```

give me `: binary operator expected`

but when I remove pipe symbol `|` it works, how to make command with pipe being executed ? I am using `sh`

Comment: Is `myFunc(true)` a pattern or a function call?

Comment: it is just a pattern

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) about the caveats involved in storing code in strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because `$($isEnabled)` is expanding to nothing and `[ -z ]` requires an argument.

- need to put `myFunc(true)` in single or double quotes since `()` has special meaning
- it is better to enclose `$indexFile` in double quotes to prevent the same issue

You can rewrite your code for `sh`:

```
function some {
  local isEnabled=$(grep 'myFunc(true)' "$indexFile" | grep true)
  if [ -z "$isEnabled" ]; then
    : your logic here
  fi
}
```

Or, more directly as:

```
function some {
  # just interested in the presence or absence of a pattern
  # irrespective of the matching line(s)
  if grep 'myFunc(true)' "$indexFile" | grep -q true; then
    : your logic here
  fi
}
```

Or, use `[[ ]]` in Bash:

```
function some {
  local isEnabled=$(grep 'myFunc(true)' "$indexFile" | grep true)
  if [[ $isEnabled ]]; then
    : your logic here
  fi
}
```

- `[[ $var ]]` is as good as `[[ -z $var ]]` or `[[ -n $var ]]`. It will evaluate to true as long as `$var` has a length > 0.
- no need to enclose variables inside `[[ ]]` in quotes - Bash handles the expansion without any word splitting or wildcard expansion issues.